# Comando para abrir janela

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script>    
window.location='https://eco2/agende-online/';  
</script>
```

Ele está dentro de um frame, gostaria de saber como faço para dar um comando de abrir e carregar a pagina toda para outra. Tentei o target mas, não funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

`window.location` altera a URL da página atual.

Para abrir uma nova janela tem que usar `window.open`, mas no seu caso parece que você quer alterar a URL de um **frame pai**, então deve usar `parent.location.href`

Exemplos de window.open, mais especificações e exemplos [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_open.asp):

```
window.open("http://www.google.com.br");
window.open("http://www.google.com.br", "_blank");
```

Exemplos de `parent.location.href`:

Arquivo teste.html (frame/pagina **pai**)

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        frame1<br/><br/>
        <iframe src="teste2.html" width="500px" height="300px"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Arquivo teste2.html (frame/página **filha** que contem o script de alterar a url)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function vai() {
                parent.location.href = "http://www.google.com.br";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        frame2 <br/>
        <input type="button" value="me clique" onclick="vai()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Então tentei o comando que passou e não está indo, a pagina simplesmente fica parada.